# Raise an Illegal Instruction in RISC-V on Purpose

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly, riscv, illegal-instruction

What is the simplest, most readable and straightforward way to **raise an illegal instruction in RISC-V** on purpose?

I know that per spec any "full zero" instruction (so 32/16 bits only zeros) is a "Defined Illegal Instruction" (section 12.5, user spec). But I have no idea if there exists an asm shorthand for that (at least I could not find any) that I could then use in inline asm in C code.

There must surely be a **portable and reliable** way to always cause an illegal instruction exception? I personally find writing to read-only registers or similar hacks quite offputting, as they are not very explicit. But maybe this is just how its done?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Any inline-asm syntax compatible with GNU C / GAS would let you use `.word 0` to emit four bytes of zeros for a RISC-V target.  There may also be a mnemonic for it, IDK.

Comment: https://reviews.llvm.org/D54316 <- try `c.unimp`

Comment: @peterCordes you are right! I can simply put "__asm__ volatile(".word 0");"  into the C code. Never would have thought that the compiler/assembler would eat that! Thanks

Comment: @dratenik Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!! Simple and explicit:     __asm__ volatile ("unimp");. Its simply zeros again, but a lot more readable.

Comment: Assemblers just assemble bytes into the output (in the current section).  GNU C inline asm works by printing this text into the compiler's asm output that will eventually be fed to an assembler.  (And clang mostly works as-if that happened, at least for things with purely local effects or `.pushsection`/`.popsection` to put some data somewhere.)  So that's why it works. But yeah, good that there's an `unimp`  mnemonic for it, that's always better than manually encoding, especially when you might compile for 16-bit compressed instructions.

Comment: ok, it works, so let's make that an answer. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mnemonic for it is `unimp`. It is [documented in the RISC-V asm manual](https://github.com/riscv-non-isa/riscv-asm-manual/blob/master/riscv-asm.md#instruction-aliases), so it should be portable.

Comment: thank you again! Link to this: https://github.com/riscv-non-isa/riscv-asm-manual/blob/master/riscv-asm.md#instruction-aliases.